# How to shrink an ext2 partition?

Tags: linux, partitioning, fdisk

I have an ext2 partition that takes up the whole disk (which is `/dev/sdc`). I have unplugged the disc and plugged into another (linux) computer.  How can I shrink this partition using `resize2fs` and `fdisk`.

Comment: Do you have cfdisk? I've found the CLI layout of it makes it really easy to use compared to fdisk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're pretty much there. First you can resize the filesystem on top of the parition by using `resize2fs /dev/sdc1 new_size`. You can then resize the underlying partition using `fdisk /dev/sdc` -- delete the partition and re-create it as the new size. Create a new partition in the newly freed space and then write the partition table + `mkfs.ext3` on the new volume.

To be safe, you should probably back up anything important first.

Comment: That's what I thought, but after writing the partition table, the file system on the new shrunk partition is corrupt.

Comment: Probably need to run an `fsck` afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Use GParted in SystemRescueCD: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysresccd

Comment: I would like to know how to do it with standard linux utilities without installing anything else thanks.

Comment: You can simply install gparted on the other computer, no need for a liveCD